# Live Data Not showing (Android Studio)

Tags: android, database, android-livedata

I was trying to run a code

```
LiveData<ArrayList<TodoModel>> liveData = todoTable.getAllTodos(db);
    todoTable.getAllTodos(db).observe(this, new Observer<ArrayList<TodoModel>>() {
        @Override
        public void onChanged(ArrayList<TodoModel> todoModels) {
            todoList.clear();
            todoList.addAll(todoModels);
            todoAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    });
```

Here is the getAllTodos method

```
public MutableLiveData<ArrayList<TodoModel>> getAllTodos(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    MutableLiveData<ArrayList<TodoModel>> liveTodos = new MutableLiveData<>();
    ArrayList<TodoModel> todos = new ArrayList<>();
            Cursor cursor = db.query(TABLE_NAME,
                    new String[]{columns.id, columns.title, columns.task, columns.category, columns.date, columns.time},
                    null, null, null,
                    null, null);
            while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
                TodoModel todo = new TodoModel(cursor.getString(1), cursor.getString(2),
                        cursor.getString(3), cursor.getLong(4), cursor.getLong(5));
                todos.add(todo);
            }
     liveTodos.setValue(todos);
    return liveTodos;
}
```

Whenver there is a change in ArrayList todos, the change is not shown immediately. But after restarting the app the new TodoModel is shown.

Comment: Your `getAllTodos()` function only updates the value of the LiveData once for each time it is called. What you need is an `observable` data source. I'd recommend Room for this, it's easier to use than raw Cursors and will allow you to observe a database table and be notified every time it changes

Comment: Thanks for the solution @IvanWool. RoomDatabase often conflict with main threads. How to use the `Observable` data source?

Comment: To be honest I'm not very up to date with best practices for background threading on Java having not used it much the last few years. If you read up on Room and are willing to try the jump to Kotlin you can use `coroutines`.

Comment: As Ivan recommended you it is better to use a room that automatically reacts to changes in the database but in this case you can return MutableLiveData from insertTodo method and observe it in ViewModel then call getAllTodos. I'm not sure it's good practice but it should work... EDITED: sorry, it will not work because it returns a new instance of LiveDate, only way is to pass it as a parameter... however it is easier with the room